# How to get elements for non-contiguous indices in a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have a numpy array:

`arr = np.array([1,2,3,4,4,5,3,2,10])`

and an indices array:

`indices = np.array([0,1,4,6])`

I could write a simple function that does the job, but I was wondering if numpy has a built-function like `np.get(arr, indices)` which returns, in this case, `np.array([1,2,4,3]`.

Comment: ```arr[indices]```?.. [numpy-indexing docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html)

Comment: Oops! Can't believe I didn't try that. Thank you!

Comment: Still read the docs though to understand what the effects are (view vs. copy)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called [Advanced Indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing):

> triggered when the selection object is a non-tuple sequence object, an ndarray (of data type integer or bool), or a tuple with at least one sequence object or ndarray (of data type integer or bool). There are two types of advanced indexing: integer and Boolean.
>
> Advanced indexing always returns a copy of the data (contrast with basic slicing that returns a view).

Your situation is integer advanced indexing, where you pass an array of indexes to be retrieved. As sascha noted in comments, this will create a copy of the data, so the new array will exist independently from the original one (i.e., writing to it  will not modify the original array).